# how do I use error function - erf with Swift language

Tags: swift

I would like to a change an objects position according to this function:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/Erf_900.gif

The function that describes the position I want is called erf - error function. It turns out that swift has erf fucntion available in it's libraries, but I can't figure out how to use it.

It says: Ambiguous use of erf

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How to call the `erf` function? How to "change  an objects position"? What kind of object? ... ?

Comment: `erf` takes a `Double`:  let n = erf(2.0)

Comment: The previous comment did the trick. I used it ambigiously because of wrong type of argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ambiguous use of erf* means that you are calling the function with a type which it does not support.

Call the function passing a Double type as the parameter:

```
let n = erf(2.0)
```

or

```
let n = erf(Double(k))
```